# NPE in OnPostExecute() of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am trying to communicate with a remote device via WHTTP. I send a request and the device responds. It does not always respond immediately which is why I use AsyncTask.

Here is some trimmed down code to explain better:

```
private class CameraSettings extends AsyncTask<AvailableCameraSettings, Void, AvailableCameraSettings> {
    private final String INNER_TAG = CameraSettings.class.getSimpleName();
    AvailableCameraSettings availableCameraSettings = new AvailableCameraSettings();


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AvailableCameraSettings availableCameraSettings) {
        if(availableCameraSettings==null){
            Log.e(INNER_TAG, "NULL");
            return;
        }
        if (availableCameraSettings.getSetting().equals(SettingType.APERTURE) ) {
            apertureSettings = availableCameraSettings;
            ArrayAdapter<String> apertureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            apertureAdapter.addAll(apertureSettings.getAvailableSettings());

            apertureSpinner.setAdapter(apertureAdapter);
            apertureSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String itemAtPosition = ((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    mCameraIO.setAperture(itemAtPosition);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            apertureSpinner.setEnabled(true);
        } else if (availableCameraSettings.getSetting().equals(SettingType.ISO)) {
            isoSettings = availableCameraSettings;
            ArrayAdapter<String> isoSpeedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            isoSpeedAdapter.addAll(isoSettings.getAvailableSettings());
            isoSpinner.setAdapter(isoSpeedAdapter);
            isoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String itemAtPosition = ((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    mCameraIO.setIsoSpeed(itemAtPosition);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            isoSpinner.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected AvailableCameraSettings doInBackground(AvailableCameraSettings... params) {
        AvailableCameraSettings parameter = params[0];
        if (parameter != null) {
            Log.d(INNER_TAG, "***** Entered doInBackground method for setting " + parameter.getSetting().getName());
        }else{
            return null;
        }

        if (parameter.getSetting().equals(SettingType.APERTURE)) {
            mCameraIO.getApertures(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, " Response is Null");
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, "Response is: " + response.toString(4));
                        extractAvailableSettings(response, apertureSettings);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraIO.ResponseCode responseCode, String responseMsg) {

                }
            });
            return apertureSettings;
        } else if (parameter.getSetting().equals(SettingType.ISO)) {
            mCameraIO.getIsoSpeedRates(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, " Response is Null");
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, "Response is: " + response.toString(4));
                        extractAvailableSettings(response, isoSettings);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraIO.ResponseCode responseCode, String responseMsg) {

                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

the error produced is:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:210)
                                                                             at com.thibaudperso.sonycamera.timelapse.fragments.CameraSettingsFragment$CameraSettings.onPostExecute(CameraSettingsFragment.java:311)
                                                                             at com.thibaudperso.sonycamera.timelapse.fragments.CameraSettingsFragment$CameraSettings.onPostExecute(CameraSettingsFragment.java:297)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Line 311 is:

```
     apertureAdapter.addAll(apertureSettings.getAvailableSettings());
```

I understand a null `List<String>` gets there, but I don't understand why `doInBackground()` doesn't wait until it gets the response, then return the newly populated object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls to getApertures() and getIsoSpeedRates() take in a callback (`CameraListener`) which means it ***already waits*** for a response without needing to use an AsyncTask.

What's happening is this case is it's getting to the onResponse *after* doInBackground completes, because it's essentially *another asynchronous task*, being called from your `CameraSettings` AsyncTask.

I suggest removing the AsyncTask altogether, and creating similar methods to the following. Note the call to `updateAdapter` is called from `onResult` - because it's at that point you actually have the result. The `onResult` is essentially the same as `onPostExecute` of an `AsyncTask`, so you need to handle your functionality in there.

```
public void getCameraSettings(AvailableCameraSettings parameter) {

        if (parameter != null) {
            Log.d(INNER_TAG, "***** Entered doInBackground method for setting " + parameter.getSetting().getName());
        }else{
            return null;
        }

        if (parameter.getSetting().equals(SettingType.APERTURE)) {
            mCameraIO.getApertures(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, " Response is Null");
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, "Response is: " + response.toString(4));
                        extractAvailableSettings(response, apertureSettings);
                        updateAdapter(SettingType.APERTURE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraIO.ResponseCode responseCode, String responseMsg) {

                }
            });
            return apertureSettings;
        } else if (parameter.getSetting().equals(SettingType.ISO)) {
            mCameraIO.getIsoSpeedRates(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, " Response is Null");
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        Log.d(INNER_TAG, "Response is: " + response.toString(4));
                        extractAvailableSettings(response, isoSettings);
                        updateAdapter(SettingType.ISO);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraIO.ResponseCode responseCode, String responseMsg) {

                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Then add a method as follows. It's essentially the same as what you had in `onPostExecute`. It looks like `isoSettings` and `apertureSettings` were member variables so I trust you have access here, but if not, add them as a parameter to be passed to this method.

```
protected void updateAdapter(String settingType) {
    if(availableCameraSettings==null){
        Log.e(INNER_TAG, "NULL");
        return;
    }
    if (settingType.equals(SettingType.APERTURE) ) {
        apertureSettings = availableCameraSettings;
        ArrayAdapter<String> apertureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        apertureAdapter.addAll(apertureSettings.getAvailableSettings());

        apertureSpinner.setAdapter(apertureAdapter);
        apertureSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String itemAtPosition = ((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                mCameraIO.setAperture(itemAtPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        apertureSpinner.setEnabled(true);
    } else if (settingType.equals(SettingType.ISO)) {
        isoSettings = availableCameraSettings;
        ArrayAdapter<String> isoSpeedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        isoSpeedAdapter.addAll(isoSettings.getAvailableSettings());
        isoSpinner.setAdapter(isoSpeedAdapter);
        isoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String itemAtPosition = ((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                mCameraIO.setIsoSpeed(itemAtPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        isoSpinner.setEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

---

**Note:** If there's a strong reason I'm missing that you *have* to use an AsyncTask - you can achieve the same by simply calling your new `updateAdapter` method from within the `onResult` within the `doInBackground`, but I think it's unnecessary.

---

Comment: Still hitting the null pointer exception. If i take the code step by step, i see that it jumps from here      [mCameraIO.getIsoSpeedRates(new CameraListener() {] directly to     [return apertureSettings;] object, which is still not populated with the required data. So to problem would be that doInBackground is not waiting for the proper response from my request.

Comment: For what it's worth i got it to work in a very buggy way, thread.sleep(2000) on each of the request i need from the camera. The line of code is inserted right above return availableSettings(iso, aperture, etc.) so i can give it time to populate the settings correctly. I am still waiting for a error proof resolution.

Comment: Is there a reason you habe this in an AsyncTask? I've just realised you are using callbacks within the doInBackground, which means you're essentially doing another asynchronous task within an async task. I'll update my answer with potential solution if you don't have to use AsyncTask, so the "inner" ones can return at any time after the doInBackground completes. I think you can get by without the AsyncTask.

Comment: I walked right past the solution and did not see it. I got rid of AsyncTask as you suggested and did my update logic in the callback methods.

Comment: Glad you got sorted @Doru